# Calculating longest sequence and average sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet with a column whose rows have a value of 0 or 1. For instance, the values for column A from rows 1 through 10 might be: `1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1`

I'd like to be able to determine the longest sequence of consecutive `0`s as well as the average number of consecutive `0`s. So for the sequence above the results would be `3` and `2.5`, respectively.

Thanks

Comment: Is it okay with you if you get a solution using helper columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you're okay with helper columns...

In cell B2, put the formula:

```
=IF(A2=0,B1+1,0)
```

And in cell C2, put the formula:

```
=IF(B2>B3,B2,0)
```

Then drag down both formulae to the bottom of the table It should be something like that:

```
    A   B   C
1
2   1   0   0
3   0   1   0
4   0   2   0
5   0   3   3
6   1   0   0
7   0   1   0
8   0   2   2
9   1   0   0
10  1   0   0
11  1   0   0
```

To get the longest sequence of consecutive `0`s, you can use:

```
=MAX(B2:B11)
```

And to get the average:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C2:C11,"<>0")
```

Comment: this was just what I needed - thank you a million times over. :-)

Comment: @ScottMitchell You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Jerry's approach, you can get the average streak without a third column. Instead, use the formula below.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11)*($B$2:$B$11>0)*($B$3:$B$12=0))/SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11>0)*($B$3:$B$12=0))
```